Screenshot from Bluestacks via ADB returns a black image after a while
This started happening suddenly; the setup was working fine for about two years:

I have an app in Bluestacks that I need to take screenshots of on a regular basis (about every 5 seconds)
WSL is taking those screenshots via adb (adb -e exec-out "screencap -p && sleep .2" > ./screen-temp.png) and doing OCR and whatever is needed... Not important at the moment

Suddenly*, this stopped working. As in - it works for about 10-20 minutes, but after that all downloaded screenshots are entirely black (but not corrupted - just an "empty" screenshot of correct size). After I restart the emulator, it works again, but fails after the expected amount of time.
This is my everyday desktop PC, and I see no other misconduct.
* After a power failure, which has happened before, but never caused any issues after a reboot.

While the root of the problem is still unknown, changing Bluestacks from using OpenGL to DirectX solved the issue. I don't know which one is default (I guess OpenGL), so I don't know why changing to DirectX solved the problem when it was working fine with OpenGL before.
